# Visual Studio 2022 + .NET Upgrade Assistant - Cant Import Controls After Conversion From .NET Framework

Tags: dll, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, windows-forms-designer, .net-4.8

We are in the process of trying to salvage an old package for current use in a WinForms application being converted from .NET Framework to .NET 6+ using the .NET Upgrade Assistant

This package was an outlook-style navigation pane control that has long since been untouched or updated and, does not survive a conversion test when attempting to convert the main application from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6 (Package/Dependencies do not support target framework etc.).

For reference, here is the package: https://github.com/jacobmesu/Guifreaks-Navisuite

We are curious if, in general, converting a project that supports custom WinForms controls can be quickly ported over to .NET or if there is much more to consider behind the scenes during the conversion.

To this point, we have tried using the .NET Upgrade Assistant and it works when converting any of the core packages from .NET Framework to .NET 6. The application even runs after the fact. However, the same DLLs that could be used to import the custom controls into the designer's Toolbox before, are now running into the error of import failing due to being unable to enumerate. Specifically:

"...dll targets a platform whose toolbox items cannot be enumerated dynamically"

We are still in the stage of gathering info on how to properly tackle this so any additional info on this specific topic is appreciated.

If this all proves too time-consuming, creating a new custom component may be considered.